# Divergent import behavior on URL and HTTPRequest

Tags: web-access

I'm playing with the IMSLP API (such as it is) and was running it through my generalized API interface which formats calls to `HTTPRequest` for reasons of flexibility, but it kept failing where it shouldn't. Specifically, this is the issue:

```
In[879]:= HTTPRequest[
  "http://imslp.org/imslpscripts/API.ISCR.php?account=worklist/disclaimer=accepted/sort=id/type=1/start=0/retformat=json"
  ]//Import
Out[879]= "Unknown account. Please see <a href='\/wiki\/IMSLP:API'>IMSLP:API<\/a> for documentation."
```

And yet this works fine if I strip the `HTTPRequest` head:

```
In[880]:= "http://imslp.org/imslpscripts/API.ISCR.php?account=worklist/disclaimer=accepted/sort=id/type=1/start=0/retformat=json"//
Lookup[Import[#,"JSON"],"0"]&
Out[880]= {type->1,id->Category:(van Luiken) Bakker, Jeroen,parent->,permlink->http://imslp.org/wiki/Category:(van_Luiken)_Bakker,_Jeroen}
```

Does anyone know why this is? What headers would `Import` be sending that `HTTPRequest` isn't?

Can confirm that `URLRead` fails here, but `URLFetch` succeeds. Of course, `URLRead` calls `URLFetch` so this just makes it weirder.

#### Edit

I figured out why this happens:

`` URLUtilities`PackageScope`doURLFetch `` uses `HTTPRequest[url]["URL"]` which splits the URL with `URLParse`, then interprets it and splices it back together with `URLBuild` and so applies something like `URLEncode` to the `"Query"` string so the `"/"` characters get converted into a form that the IMSLP API can't deal with.

Which means I'm in the market for a work-around. I would prefer to continue to use `HTTPRequest` if possible, but will probably just have to swap back to a `URLFetch` structure.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around this by providing an override for `URLQueryEncode`. Since the strings that gave me trouble were those that I'd already built using a special `"QuerySeparator"` I was able to get away with this override:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{URLQueryEncode},
  Unprotect@URLQueryEncode;
  URLQueryEncode[{k_ -> 
      s_String?(StringContainsQ[a["QuerySeparator"]])}] :=

   k <> "=" <> s;
  URLRead[HTTPRequest@w, args]
  ];
```

The `w` there is an API call object, but it formats out to a url and metainfo for an `HTTPRequest`. Using this I'm able to use it with `URLRead` and friends.